# Bulk insert or update for the given where

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function that gets `$homes` and `$member_id` as parameters. `$homes` is an array, `$member_id` is an integer.

```
$homes = array( 'home13', 'home21', 'home34', 'home44' );
$member_id = 5;
```

How do I insert/update into the following DB?

[image]

in the format:

```
id  home_name member_id
1   home13     5
2   home21     5
2   home34     5
2   home44     5
```

The function I used:

```
public function store($homes, $member_id) {
      foreach( $homes as $home ) {
            $data[] = [ 'member_id' => $member_id, 'home_name' => $home ];
        }
      Home::insert( $data );
}
```

which works fine while inserting. However, I need to update all records for a given `$member_id` if the member_id already exists.

For example, if the `$member_id` is 5 and `$homes` is now `array( 'home54' )`, all other `home_name` that are previously stored for the `$member_id` 5 should be deleted. so that the following would only remain.

```
id  home_name member_id
1   home54     5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Laravel's `upsert()` method

Example:

```
Home::upsert([
    ['home_name' => 'home54', 'member_id' => 5, 'id' => 1],
    ['home_name' => 'home13', 'member_id' => 5, 'id' => 2],
    ['home_name' => 'home21', 'member_id' => 5, 'id' => 3],
], ['member_id', 'id'], ['home_name']);
```

This method consists of three arguments.

1. Values to insert/update
2. Columns that uniquely identify the values
3. The values that need to be updated

Please note that you need to use a unique composite key to use `upsert()` method.

Example from Seeder class:

```
$table->unique(['member_id','id']);
```

Reference from Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts

Answer (score 0):

You can use `updateOrCreate` method to achieve this

```
public function store($homes, $member_id) {
  foreach( $homes as $home ) {
        Home::updateOrCreate( 'member_id' => $member_id, 'home_name' => $home );
    }
  }
```